# Order Id: Popup modal in magento 2

Tags: sales-order, ajax, jquery, magento2.2

I have **overrided** the core(**history.phtml corin module-sales**) phtml file and created the **custom link** using **popup modal** to **update** the **custom status** as cancel initiated. And it **works** only for the **last** **order id**. If I click another **id** to update, again it updated for only the **last id**. But it **does not** get the **current id** to **update**. How to get the **current id before model loads?** Image for reference. please provide me a solution.
[image]

**history.phtml**

```
<?php $_orders = $block->getOrders(); ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('info') ?>
<?php if ($_orders && count($_orders)): ?>
    <div class="table-wrapper orders-history">
        <table class="data table table-order-items history" id="my-orders-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Orders') ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order #') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Date') ?></th>
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header') ?>
                    <th scope="col" class="col shipping"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Ship To') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col total"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order Total') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Status') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col actions"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Action') ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
                        <?php $extra = $block->getChildBlock('extra.container'); ?>
                        <?php if ($extra): ?>
                            <?php $extra->setOrder($_order); ?>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $extra->getChildHtml() ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Ship To')) ?>" class="col shipping"><?= $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $block->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Actions')) ?>" class="col actions">
                            <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewUrl($_order) ?>" class="action view">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('View Order') ?></span>
                            </a>
                            <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder')->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>
                                <a href="#" data-post='<?php
                                /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo
                                        $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper::class)
                                        ->getPostData($block->getReorderUrl($_order))
                                ?>' class="action order">
                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Reorder') ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <div> **I have added my custom link here**
                                <a href="#" id="click" class="click-me" data-id="<?= $_order->getEntityId(); ?>" >Cancel</a>

                            </div>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('You have placed no orders.') ?></span></div>
<?php endif ?>


<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">
    <form action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'oxsales/index/index'; ?> " method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
        <div id="result"></div>
        <div>   <label>Reason:</label><textarea id="reason" rows="4" cols="60" name="reason"></textarea></div>

    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
    "*": {
    "cancelreasonScript": {}
    }
    }
</script>
```

**js file**

```
require(['jquery', 'mage/url', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'], function (jQuery, url, modal) {

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Reason for Cancelled the item',

                buttons: [{
                        text: jQuery.mage.__('submit'),
                        class: '',
                        click: function () {
                            var cancelreason = jQuery("#reason").val();

                            var orderId = jQuery('#click').data('id');
                             var cancelurl = url.build("oxsales/index/index/");
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url: cancelurl,
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {'id': orderId, 'cancelreason': cancelreason},
                                success: function (response) {

                                    jQuery("#result").html("Cancel initiated for your request");
                                },
                                error: function (response) {
                                    jQuery("#result").html("Error");
                                }
                            });
                            var close = this;
                            setTimeout(function () {

                                close.closeModal();
                            }, 3000);
                        }
                    }]
            };

            jQuery(".click-me").on('click', function () {
               var popup = modal(options, jQuery('#popup-modal'));
                jQuery('#reason').val('');

                jQuery("#result").html('');

                jQuery("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");

            });
        }
        );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move whole var options block into onclick callback and inside use

`$(this).data('id');`

to get order's id;

Comment: No it is not working. still it gets the last order id 10

Comment: how to get the current id before model loads

Comment: yes, I got it through click event, but how to pass it, to popup modal?